# How to disable an item in a Spinner

Tags: android

Is it possible to display particular entries in a Spinner list as disabled?

I.e., I want to always display a spinner with four entries (North, South, East, and West, say), but I want to be able to disable any one of these so that is appears greyed out and not selectable.

Is this possible, or will I have to recreate the list each time, leaving out the invalid entries?

Comment: possible duplicate of [android change text color of items in spinner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836254/android-change-text-color-of-items-in-spinner)

Comment: @Jason, it is the same, but mine was here first. Doesn't that make his the duplicate?

Comment: it doesn't matter who's was the duplicate, only that duplicates exist and can be archived as such.

Comment: **Not a duplicate**: changing the color and disabling an item are not related

Comment: it does matter because you have people that will downvote duplicates so it matters which one is the duplicate.

Answer (score 45):

```
   // Create spinner month, and disable month < today
    List<CharSequence> listMonth = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();
    for (int m = 0; m < 12; m++) {
        if (m < 9) {
            listMonth.add("0" + (m + 1));
        } else {
            listMonth.add("" + (m + 1));
        }
    }
        // Create spinner item
    adapterMonth = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
            R.layout.layout_spinner_item, listMonth) {
         // Disable click item < month current
        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (year <= max_year && position < max_month - 1) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        // Change color item
        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View mView = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
            TextView mTextView = (TextView) mView;
            if (year <= max_year && position < max_month - 1) {
                mTextView.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            } else {
                mTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
            return mView;
        }
    };

    adapterMonth
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spn2.setAdapter(adapterMonth);
```

Comment: Worked like a freakkiiiing charm! Thank you! :)

Comment: That is correct but in instead of  `TextView mTextView = (TextView) mView;`
you have to use `TextView mTextView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.layout.layout_spinner_item);`

Answer (score 9):

```
    public class MySpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public void isEnabled(int position) {
       return getItem(position).isEnabled(); 
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

      if(convertView == null) {
          convertView = View.inflate(parent.getContext(), R.layout.item, null);
      }
      if(!isEnabled(position)) {
          convertView.setEnabled(false);
          convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                //NO-OP: Just intercept click on disabled item
             }
          });
      }

      return convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Someone just posted a solution to your problem, refer to this [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836254/android-change-text-color-of-items-in-spinner).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @AaronHall it's a link to stack overflow, so the link will very likely remain viable.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this possible

It doesn't appear so. The way you would do that with `ListView` involves `areAllItemsEnabled()` and `isEnabled()`. However, those are methods on the `ListAdapter` interface, not the `SpinnerAdapter` interface. So, I suspect they will be ignored by a `Spinner`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class SpinnerAdapter(context: Context, resource: Int, list: ArrayList<String>)
    : ArrayAdapter<String>(context, resource, list) {

        override fun isEnabled(position: Int): Boolean {
            // select position to disable 
            return position != 0
        }

}
```