# Modify color Android selected Dropdown item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar, android-spinner

How can I modify the text color of the selected item on a Spinner in an Android Honeycomb application?

EDIT:
I have a Spinner layout which i'm inflating. Is it possible to add an attribute in this spinner to change the text color? I was able to change the background for example using the android:background on the spinner, but I'm not able to do the same with android:textColor.

Comment: Have a Look at this nice post [android change text color of items in spinner][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836254/android-change-text-color-of-items-in-spinner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used this code for ListView adaper:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View rowView;
        EntSaleDocumentDetails entSaleDocumentDetails = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.myLayout,
                    null);
        } else {
            rowView = (View) convertView;
        }


        TextView myTv= (TextView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvCode);

        myTv.setTextSize(16);

        //....

        // set selected item
        LinearLayout ActiveItem = (LinearLayout) rowView;
        if (position == selectedItem)
        {
            ActiveItem
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_dark_blue);
        }
        else
        {
            ActiveItem
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border02);
        }
        //....
}

public void setSelectedItem(int position) {
        selectedItem = position;
    }
```

your custom layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="@drawable/border02"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/back_color_selector03"
        android:gravity="right" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="TextView" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCode"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llProductDetails"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/back_color_selector_blue_simple" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnProductDetails"
            android:layout_width="40dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:src="@drawable/prd_details" />

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tblProductDetails"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvQty"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkText" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvLblQty"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dip"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkText" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvStockQty"
                    android:layout_width="100dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dip"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkText" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvLblStockQty"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dip"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkText" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvMablagh"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkText" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvLblMablagh"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dip"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkText" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvFee"
                    android:layout_width="100dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dip"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkText" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvLblFee"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dip"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkText" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and in activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(parent, view, position, id);
        adapter.setSelectedItem(position);
        myListView.invalidateViews();
    }
```

Comment: I have a Spinner layout which i'm inflating. Is it possible to add an attribute in this spinner to change the text color? I was able to change the background for example using the android:background on the spinner, but I'm not able to do the same with android:textColor.

Comment: define your own layout. get that TextView like this: rowView.findViewById(...) and set your color