# why dropdown spinner is not show on screen?

Tags: android

Hi I have required dropdownlist like in image[image]

for that My code is as:-

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="60dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
            android:text="Picture"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18dip" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="34dp"
            android:layout_height="40dip" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/picturelist"
            android:layout_width="206dp"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:entries="@array/picture_arrays"
            android:prompt="@string/prompt"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

but output is as shown in image:-[image]

please anyone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead..

```
<Spinner
  android:id="@+id/picturelist"
  android:layout_width="206dp"
  android:layout_height="30dip"
  android:ellipsize="end"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:imeOptions="actionNext"
  android:entries="@array/picture_arrays"
  android:prompt="@string/prompt"
  android:textColor="#000000" />
```

**Edit:**
           To Change the Color,Please **[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836254/android-change-text-color-of-items-in-spinner)**

Comment: sorry textcolor is not there. please give me answer how change color because it looks very fed?

Comment: see the link that i have provided in my link

Comment: please give me proper link ,I unable to find related post.

Answer (score 0):

I can see the dropdown on the lower-right (light grayed color). If you want it to be fairly visible, increase the contrast like changing its color in contrast with the background color of the activity.

Comment: but its dropdown also in black color and open above the spinner?and what color should be there?

Comment: set something like this: android:backgroound="#FFFF00", if you want yellow background.