# how to apply condition not null and some selected item from spinner in android

Tags: android

```
public class roleeditpage extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    String rolenUrl = "http://182.71.212.110:8083/api/values/updaterole?";
    private Spinner rolespinner;
    TextView roletext;
    String roleitem;
    String result;
    Button editbutton;
    String ID;
    TextView emplname;
    String EmployeName;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    ImageView backbutton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.editrole);
        backbutton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgBack);
        roletext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itemtext);
        editbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        rolespinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        emplname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.emplname);
        editbutton.setOnClickListener(this);
        backbutton.setOnClickListener(this);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        ID = bundle.getString("id");
        EmployeName = bundle.getString("empname");
        final String[] role = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.Circle);

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.spinner_item, role);
        dataAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // set the ArrayAdapter to the spinner
        rolespinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        emplname.setText(EmployeName);
    }

    class role extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(roleeditpage.this);
            pDialog.setTitle("Update");
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            roleitem = rolespinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

            System.out.println(roleitem);
            try {



                result = HttpHitter.ExecuteData(rolenUrl + "id=" + ID
                        + "&designation="
                        + URLEncoder.encode(roleitem, "UTF-8"));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.e("ressss", rolenUrl + "id=" + ID + "&designation=" + roleitem);
            System.out.println(result);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            finish();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {



            if(roleitem !=null|| !roleitem.equals("Select You Circle"))
            {
                new role().execute();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please Select role ",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
        if (v.getId() == R.id.imgBack) {
            finish();
        }

    }

}
```

Below is my Itemlist of Spinner value:

```
<string-array name="Circle">
    <item>Select You Circle</item>
    <item>ANE</item>
    <item>BNJ</item>
    <item>Delhi</item>
    <item>GUJRAT</item>
    <item>HP</item>
    <item>Haryana</item>
    <item>KARNATAKA</item>
    <item>MNG</item>
    <item>MPCG</item>
    <item>ROB</item>
    <item>Punjab</item>
    <item>Rajastan</item>
    <item>UPE</item>
    <item>UPW</item>
</string-array>
```

i want to apply validation if on Spinner item value  i want to apply condition When Select You Circle  select and click on button then value should not take there should toast message display please select circle apart from that value should work . i am trying to apply this using

```
if(roleitem !=null|| !roleitem.equals("Select You Circle"))
                {
                    new role().execute();
                }
```

code but it is not working please tell me where is issue why i am doing mistake

Comment: Use && instead of || (if(roleitem !=null && !roleitem.equals("Select You Circle")) { new role().execute(); })

Comment: declare roleitem as String roleitem;

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
    if(rolespinner.getSelectedItemPosition() != 0)
                {
                    new role().execute();
                }
 else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please Select role ",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Comment: but it always call else condition when i select Other item

Comment: which problem can you tell me?

Comment: please check my code and Edit i have tried ur Given code its NullPointer Exception coming in given line

Comment: But i want show Toast messgge when User take SelectYou Circel from drop down it should print please select Circl value should take all aprart Select You Circle its not working

Answer (score 0):

try this.

declare this globally

`String roleitem;`

```
if(!("").equals(rolespinner.getSelectedItem().toString()) ||
!(rolespinner .getSelectedItem().toString()).equalsIgnoreCase("Select You Circle"))
{
                    new role().execute();
}
```

add this in your `oncreate()` and try

```
Toast.makeText(activityname.this,
                        "Please Select role ",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {
 
   
   
   if(!("").equals(rolespinner.getSelectedItem().toString()) ||
     !(rolespinner .getSelectedItem().toString()).equalsIgnoreCase("Select  designations"))
     {
                         new role().execute();
     }
   else
   {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
      "Please Select role ",
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

  }

Comment: http://snag.gy/WEgnu.jpg  please check this image when i Select designations  then it should display please select role in toast

Comment: oo u want to disable first item of the spinner to select ? im i correct?

Comment: ok go to ur xml and add prompt to spinner..`android:prompt="Select You Role"` ...and `android:spinnerMode="dialog"`

Comment: yes it should just visible but it take Null item if we select that

Comment: but i want set by default select Your Role in Spinner it should not select By default

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836254/android-change-text-color-of-items-in-spinner

Comment: and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836254/android-change-text-color-of-items-in-spinner

Comment: look m y code i have tried same way i am able to visbile in drop  down but Problem is that select your Circel this also coming when open spinner